# Table in Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a table in a Bootstrap 3.3.7 drop-down.
Ideally, I would like to display the table header as well.

https://codepen.io/Falven/pen/YjyrKX

```css
.dropdown {
  display: table;
}

.dropdown-menu li {}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  display: table-row;
}

.dropdown-menu li a span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
    <table class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <a href="#">
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
        </a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Row1Col1-abcdefghijk</span>
          <span>Row1Col2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Row2Col1</span>
          <span>Row2Col2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Row3Col1</span>
          <span>Row3Col2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was able to get something working in Bootstrap 4, but even this is not fully working.

https://codepen.io/Falven/pen/bjVaGN

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: table-row;
}

.dropdown-item span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <span>Row1Col1</span>
      <span>Row1Col2</span>
    </a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <span>Row2Col1</span>
      <span>Row2Col2</span>
    </a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <span>Row3Col1</span>
      <span>Row3Col2</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't alter the framework, work within it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr>
          <th>File Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <a href="#">
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
          </a>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is the highlighting and bootstrap css is not longer working since we messed up the DOM, for example, the CSS targets: .dropdown-menu > li > a etc.

Comment: It's not a huge deal because we are using angular and can use ng-click, but you can't have anchors in tables... It's against the spec. So this solution may not work for everyone.

Comment: what spec? html? You really need to show me that spec.